# Why does the system said that I had no more free disk space?

Tags: disk-management

There should be a lot of space that I can use.
[image]

Comment: How did u boot?did u booted as a partition or just single os ? please tell me about your booting procedure we are ready to help you out

Comment: There are 2 partitions, one for the OS, one for /home

Comment: Did you check the OS partition as well?